# Dynamic Gridview CalendarExtender is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendarextender

I have DropdownList and after user select from it,  it generates Gridview from db ( the db table depends on dropdownlist selectedindex). I want to add CalendarExtender to dynamic cell( in c# code without html) which has "start" as a column name.

My code:

```
if (DataTable.Columns[i].ToString() == "start_date_time")
                    {
                        
                        TxtBox.ID = DataTable.Columns[i].ToString();
                        TxtBox.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static;
                        DBTableGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i+1].Controls.Add(TxtBox);

                        CalendarExtender CalendarExtender1 = new CalendarExtender();
                        CalendarExtender1.TargetControlID = TxtBox.ID;
                        CalendarExtender1.ID = "CalendarExtender1"+i;
                        CalendarExtender1.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                        DBTableGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(CalendarExtender1);


                    }
```

I have button that Add new row with empty Textboxes and DropdownList.When i click on it, it shows that row.But after add  DBTableGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(CalendarExtender1); that row is not showing.

What can i do? Thank you for your time.

Comment: it's a bit unclear what you mean when you say "whole program is working fine until last row". and "when I add it and try to add new row nothing happened".  provide enough code to reproduce the issue, and clarify a bit what is and is not working in respect to this `CalendarExtender` being programmatically added.

Comment: Sorry! I have button for adding a new row(rows[0]) in the gridview which shows empty textboxes and dropdownlists with text. After i add "DBTableGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i+1].Controls.Add(CalendarExtender) and press that button again that row for adding new values in gridview is not showing. 
In the HTML code i have:
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
             <asp:GridView ID="DBTableGrid" runat="server" CssClass="GridDataStyle">